# Asking stack to pass extra command-line arguments to c2hs

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, c2hs

I use [c2hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/c2hs) for easing the process of writing Haskell bindings to C/C++ libraries.  I also recently started using stack for managing my Haskell projects.

To use c2hs, I need to have a line saying `#include "myheader.h"` inside my Haskell source code; here `myheader.h` is the interface file to my C/C++ libraries.

I found out today, that instead of embedding this `#include` line into the `.chs` source file, one can also pass the location of the header file while invoking c2hs as follows

`c2hs   /<path-to-my-header>/myheader.h    Foo.chs`

Thankfully, stack automatically detects when a file has a .chs extension and then calls c2hs on it. My question is, how do I tell stack to pass this extra command-line argument (i.e. the location of the header-file) while calling c2hs? 
What changes will I need to make to my .cabal or my stack.yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your location in the `include-dirs` field under the library or executable section (depending on your project) in the cabal file should make it work.